# SonarQube 5.5 and Views plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.5

As per SQ 5.5 release notes, it seems “Views” plugin would be deprecated and replaced by “Governance” plugin.
Please refer to following ticket for more details : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7428

1. What would be the support option for anyone using "views" plugin
   with community edition?
2. SQ 5.5 release date was 22 April 2016 but it has not been released as of 25 April 2016. What is the new release date for SQ 5.5 release?

Comment: There are 2 questions in your initial question. The first one is about a commercial plugin, so you should contact SonarSource support (if you are already using Views, this means you are a customer). For the second one, I will answer below.

Comment: To save some Googling for anyone finding this page: [Governance](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Governance+Plugin) is only available for the [Enterprise version](https://www.sonarsource.com/solutions/deployments/enterprise-grade/), which costs €50.000 (per annum, I assume, though that is not detailed on the page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SonarQube 5.5 will be officially released at the end of April / early beginning of May.