# Non-commercial alternatives to Views plugin for SonarQube Community Edition 5.6

Tags: sonarqube

Are there alternatives to Views plugin for Community Edition 5.6? Not commercial plugins (Governance license). Cannot comment in [SonarQube 5.5 and Views plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838766/sonarqube-5-5-and-views-plugin).

Comment: Did you ever find an alternative ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as we *(SonarSource)* know, there's no alternative to the Governance product - may it be open-source or even commercial.